# Creating a pop-up dialog when specific page is loaded in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to create a google extension that shows a pop-up dialog when a specific page is loaded (e.g. stackoverflow.com).

Is that possible? If so, how?

Comment: Define a *content script* in manifest.json, insert a div or iframe (see *web_accessible_resources*), apply CSS.

Comment: And how I filter for url?

Comment: You'll see in the documentation and demo extensions.